# How to determine the row id from a column field - SQLite 3, Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, foreign-keys

In my SQLite database I have a table called client_dir that is a directory of client contact details. I also have a table called contracts that contains the details of different contracts. I need to be able to create foreign keys that bind a contract entry to a client entry in client_dir.

The thing is , I want to be able to generate the foreign key by just providing the clients name. How do I summon the row id from a field entry?

I think it should look something like this...

```
def new_contract():
    '''creates a new contract entry and links it to a client in the client_dir table'''
    client = input("Company name...")
    #int(row_id) = client
    contract = input("New contract...")
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (?)",contract,#row_id)
```

**UPDATE**

My tables look like this :

```
self.cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE client_dir(cli_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, company TEXT, address TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)""")
self.cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE contracts(con_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, contract TEXT, client_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client_dir(cli_id))""")
```

and my new _contract method looks like this:

```
def new_contract(self):
    '''creates a new contract entry and links it to a client in the client_dir table'''
    client = input("Company name...")

    for f_list in self.cursor.execute("SELECT cli_id FROM client_dir WHERE company = (?)",[client]):
        f_key = f_list[0]

        print(f_key) # For debugging 

        contract = input("New contract...")
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (NULL,?,?)",([contract],[f_key]))
```

print(f_key) is printing a nice tidy 1 on the screen which I am presuming is an int. but I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
c.new_contract()
File "C:\Python33\smalltime\Client.py", line 63, in new_contract
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (NULL,?,?)",([contract],[f_key]))
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Why the `rowid`? Don't the client contact details have a primary key?

Comment: either way, I need to get an int that represents the row from passing in an element of that row so I can feed it in as the foreign key. When someone has typed in all their contact details they are not going to remember which order they typed them in, they need to able to type in the name of the contact and have the program attach the contract to that contact.

Comment: Are you asking for `SELECT rowid FROM client_dir WHERE name = ?`?

Comment: That appears to be looking over the column names rather than column contents.

Comment: This looks at the contents of the `name` column.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. This is returning a sqlite3.cursor object though and I need an int.

Comment: Read some [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this now. The error was due to the fact I was passing in the wrong syntax for the  INSERT.

The correct last line of the new_contract method should be:

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO contracts VALUES (NULL,?,?)",**([contract,f_key]))**
```

(previously it had two extra braces : ([contract],[f_key]) and that was throwing it out)

so all that remains to do is remove the print statement and add

```
self.conn.commit()
```

to the end.